# "In the meanwhile" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

How to say **in the meanwhile** in German?

Direct translation showed "in der Zwischenzeit", but I couldn't tell if it works for sentences like "In the meanwhile I went to drink coffee".

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Show the translation you came up with for the given sentence and tell us, what you do not like about it...

Comment: In English, to nitpick, isn't it either "in the meantime I went..." Or just "meanwhile I went...", I don't recall having heard "in the meanwhile" before (in American English anyways)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In the meanwhile I went to drink coffee.

can be translated as:

> - **In der Zwischenzeit** ging ich einen Kaffee trinken.
> - **Inzwischen** ging ich einen Kaffee trinken.
> - **Währenddessen** ging ich einen Kaffee trinken.
> - **Derweil** ging ich einen Kaffee trinken.
> - **Unterdessen** ging ich einen Kaffee trinken.
> - **Zwischenzeitlich** ging ich einen Kaffee trinken.
> - **Solange** ging ich einen Kaffee trinken.
> - **Bis dahin** ging ich einen Kaffee trinken.

Comment: @Crissov: Das war ein Tippfehler, den ich per copy&paste vervielfältigt habe. Ich habe den Fehler korrigiert. Deutsches und österreichisches Deutsch unterscheiden sich zwar in sehr vielen Dingen (Wortschatz, Grammatik, Aussprache), die Rechtschreibung ist aber genau gleich. Es gibt nur sehr wenige Ausnahmen davon, z.B. »Geschoss« in D, aber »Geschoß« in Ö (sowohl Projektil als auch Stockwerk). Der Grund ist hier die andere Aussprache (kurzes ö in D, langes in Ö). Aber wie gesagt: Unterschiedliche Rechtschreibung gleicher Wörter ist ausgesprochen selten.

Comment: @Crissov: Danke auch für deine weiteren Beispiele, ich habe sie meiner Antwort hinzugefügt.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the most fitting translation in all day use is:

**Während** or **Währenddessen**.

So your sentence would be something like 'Währenddessen bin ich Kaffe trinken gegangen.'

*If you however want to use Während*, you're implying a subordinate clause. It's something like the english 'while'. 'While I was drinking a coffee, my mobile rang' would translate to 'Während ich einen Kaffee trank, hat mein Handy geklingelt'.